# How to save files to the external storage with Ionic and Capacitor in Android 13?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, capacitor-plugin

I am making an app with ionic v7 capacitor v5 with the help of angular16, i am trying to save a text file to android phone Directory.Data folder with help of capacitor filesystem writefile method.

it doesn't work. I tried almost everything but nothing works for android 13

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.